# Concat each loop Iteration result in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-sheets

I'm new to JS and developing in general and I'm kind of stuck here.

I want to use a google Sheet as a backend and query it with js/jquery. I queried the sheet correctly and parsed every row of it (achieved with a forEach).
The results from column D and B are combined to a string in the end.
I got this working, but, of course, I have 5 outputs or so.

So at the moment, every row (5 rows in the sheet) is a single output, concatenated to a string, so the final output is: output(d[i])+string+output(b[j]) , where i and j are the variables from the for loops.

The result in the console is:

```
(index):103 AccessRequestPending
(index):103 AccesssDenied
(index):103 NotConfirmed
(index):103 toOldVersion
(index):103 UnknownReason
```

These are the results, when I run the script (only for column D). 
I can't push the results to an array, because it pushes the result 5 times to the same array. So in the end, there's just one array with [UnknownReason],  But I need 1 array(or just the strings, it doesn't matter) with the 5 results concatenated.

I'd like to achieve something like

output(d[i1])+string+output(b[j1]) + 
output(d[i2])+string+output(b[j2]) + output(d[i3])+string+output(b[j3])

So, I really want to figure it out by myself, but can you tell me how to use every output/result of an iteration and concat it with the iteration before? Or maybe extract each result to it's own variable?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: it might help to share a code snippet that currently gives you the results you are seeing.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you want to sum all those cells and get the total, if that is your question,  you can use JavaScript [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to concatenate your array in a single result.

Another options can be:

- [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [ForEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Let me know if this solve your question.

Best

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I wasn't available. I combined these 2 arrays into one to map with each other.

```
let arrayCombined2 = reasonsArray.reduce(function(arr, v, i) {
     return arr.concat(v, arrayUrls[i])}
```

or for jquery:

```
let arrayCombined = $.map(reasonsArray, function(k, i) {
return [k, arrayUrls[i]];
```